# defining timeout on execution of shell/python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am having an issue with execution of my python script which are getting called from Shell script. Since due to some issue execution of one Python script is taking huge amount of time.. 
Now in this case I would like to setup a timeout on my python script where if its taking more then "n" minute, execution of current script should terminate and move to next script execution.

```
MasterScript.sh file contain multiple Python scripts  like

script1.py 
script2.py  - this script is taking more time.. if it more then 5 minute, script execution should terminiate and move to next one.
script3.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say this is your test1.py script :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import time
import sys
sys.stdout.write("in test1\n")
time.sleep(20)
sys.stdout.write("Done")
```

This is should sleep for 20 seconds before printing "Done" but be we will kill it from our shell script.

Another test.py script which runs after test1.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.stdout.write("In test2\n")
sys.stdout.write("Done")
```

Now your shell script which runs them:

```
#! /bin/bash

timeout 10 python test1.py 
python test2.py
```

Comment: timeout: invalid option -- 'k'
Try `timeout --help' for more information.
In test2

Comment: @kumarb , can you remove "-k 12" and see if it works. ?

Comment: thanks, its working for me now.. Just got one doubt now.. I am running script like timeout 110 java weblogic.WLST /tmp/anu/Stopscript.py >> $logFileName       but this is not printing the execution output in $logfilename ...

Comment: @kumarb Does it print anything on the STDOUT (screen) when not redirecting the output to your logfile ?

Comment: I got it worked now.. Thanks a lot  dear .. u rock !

Answer (score 3):

Use `timeout`

```
timeout --kill-after=305 300 script2.py
```

Comment: is this timeout function is a inbuild function and be used directly inside our code ..? could you please edit with some example code

Comment: timeout is the shell command which is used to run another command with a time limit.  Check man timeout in your UNIX/Linux shell

Comment: `timeout` is a part of coreutils. You definitely should have it installed. This will sleep for two seconds `timeout 2 sleep 10`.

Comment: thanks.. I am trying to find a sample on how I can implement this in my code.. if you dont mind, could you please put some sample code.